# Get the rows of file from list of values from 2 different files?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, rows

I want to get the single file from two different files based on the list of values.

For example:
  File 1

```
    ID    G1     G2     G3     G4    G5
    E1     1      5      0     Inf    1
    E2     2      6      4      0     9
    E3     4      5      7      8    10
    E4     2      8      3      1     1
    E5     6      7      8      0     9
    E6     12     34     5      6    11
    E7     15     7     18     29    34
    E8      0     5     23     16     7
    E3      3    32      4     18    12
   ..........
```

File 2

```
    ID    C1     C2     
    E1     A      B 
    E2     C      A
    E3     B      D
    E4     A      D
    E3     C      D
    E5     B      C
    E6     D      B
    E7     C      A 
    E8     B      A
   ..........
```

If I have the list of values E1, E5, E7, E3; then

Output should be printed to a file:

```
    ID    G1     G2     G3     G4    G5    C1     C2 
    E1     1      5      0     Inf    1    A      B
    E5     2      6      4      0     9    B      C
    E7     4      5      7      8    10    C      A
    E3     2      8      3      1     1    B      D
    E3      3    32      4     18    12    C      D
```

How can I extract with bash command:

Answer (score 0):

if the filenames are file1, file2 and file3, then this should work

```
len=`wc -l file1|awk {'print $1'}`;for i in `seq 1 $len`; do as=`sed -n "$i"p file1`; sd=`sed -n "$i"p file2`; echo "$as $sd" >> file3; done
```

Comment: While your code combines, side-by-side, the contents of the two files into a single file it does not produce the expected output results as it's not taking into account "If I have the list of values E1, E5, E7, E3; then" as shown in the output under "Output should be printed to a file:".

Comment: @user3439894  .. nice that you showed not considering a list .